# Ruby on Rails - Deivse - See Currently Signed In Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

I am using Devise for my users to log into my Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 web application. I'm unfamiliar with how sessions work. They are managed by the browser and not the application right?

I would like to get a list of users who are currently online. And eventually do some kind of background process to automatically update this list.

How would I accomplish this? Is there a gem that would assist?

Thank you,

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is have a column `last_seen_at` and update that column in your `current_user` method:

```
def current_user
  # Stuff...
  @current_user.update_attributes(:last_seen_at => DateTime.now)
  @current_user
end
```

Then consider anyone who was last seen in the last 5 minutes as "currently signed in".

Comment: You canse use devise :trackable to get this behavior from devise. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Thank you mischa, looks like that will be a good way to do it. Have a before_filter to change that value before every request, and then compare the times. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I just feel that updating that attribute on every quest is a lot. How much performance would I lose for setting a simple value like this? Let me know if there are other ways to accomplish what I desire. Thanks again!

Comment: @ardavis - It's just an update on one column in one database row. I don't think it makes a difference unless your app gets a lot of requests. If it really bothers you that it happens on every request, you could build in a check to see when the column was last changed and only do the update if the last change was longer than 4 minutes ago.